# Azure backup fails as soon as I add in the database

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to get Azure to backup my Storage as well as my Database. The reason the db backup is failing is because

> Database connection string not valid for database
>   mysite.database.windows.net (SQLAzure). Format of the
>   initialization string does not conform to specification starting at
>   index 0.

but I can't figure out which connection that is referring to and where I change it. It doesn't help that Microsoft's documentation on Azure sucks because they keep changing the interface.

You can see in the screenshot below how it my backup is succeeding when I exclude the db.

[image]

Under the Linked Database Settings there is no connection string or anything that I can change. So I have no idea how to fix this.

Is this a key-value pair that I can add in the

```
<appSettings>
  ... 
</appSettings>
```

of my `web.config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the database connection string via **Data Connections** as below snapshot. The linked Database setting blade will list all the database you configured in **Data Connections**.
[image]

You don't need to add connection string in appSettings, after you add the database in **Data Connections**, the connection string is applied automatically.